# Generalized way for renaming sql result column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

The title isn't quite clear but I will try to explain my situation better.

I have a sql statement,

```
SELECT Name,Year FROM Fruit
GROUP BY Name,Year
```

and I get the below result

```
id | name    | year   |
-----------------------
1  | Apple   | 2019   |
2  | Apple   | 2020   |
3  | Apple   | 2021   |
4  | Orange  | 2017   |
5  | Orange  | 2018   |
6  | Orange  | 2019   |
7  | Mango   | 2022   |
8  | Mango   | 2023   |
9  | Mango   | 2024   |
```

I want something like this :

```
id | name    | year   |
-----------------------
1  | Apple   | Y1     |
2  | Apple   | Y2     |
3  | Apple   | Y3     |
4  | Orange  | Y1     |
5  | Orange  | Y2     |
6  | Orange  | Y3     |
7  | Mango   | Y1     |
8  | Mango   | Y2     |
9  | Mango   | Y3     |
```

I cannot use a CASE statement because the values in the column are not always the same. But the number of rows in the Group by is always 3. Anyway I can achieve this generalized functionality without considering every different value?

Comment: "... number of rows  ... is always 3". This is based on an assumption currently. Your test data is obviously limited. Notice also that you have different years for different fruits. Once aggregated, no one will know that <Apple, Y1> is not the "same" as <Orange, Y1>. "Solutions" like this can easily lead to issues at a later date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select f.name, f.year, 
       concat('Y', row_number() over(partition by f.name order by f.year)) as years
from Fruit f;
```